# Application reference to mongo cluster

Tags: mongodb, dns

Any application that needs to connect to a MongoDB replica set will probaby have a URI of the following [sort](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/) for connecting to the replica set: `mongodb://host-1,host-2,host-3/?replicaSet=myReplicaSet`. It effectively enumerates the different hostnames of the replica set members.

A MongoDB replica set is, however, a dynamic thing, and the list of members could change during the lifetime of an application. That's fine for the most part -- I believe if it can connect to a single one of the hosts listed in the URI, it'll discover any other members of the current RS.

If the replica set's membership has complete turnover however, and no MongoDB process is listening on `host-1`, `host-2`, or `host-3`, but now they're all at `host-4`, `host-5`, and `host-6`, the URI stops being useful.

My question, then, is: what's the right way to guarantee that your application has a reference to the replica set that can never be invalidated?

You could use a staggered approach with cnames. Give the application a reference `mongodb://host-a,host-b,host-c/?replicaSet=myReplicaSet`, and then, as servers are added / removed to the replica  set, the cnames are updated.

Initial state:

```
CNAMES: host-a -> host-1, host-b -> host-2, host-c -> host-3
RS: host-1, host-2, host-3
```

Add a server to the RS:

```
CNAMES: host-a -> host-1, host-b -> host-2, host-c -> host-3
RS: host-1, host-2, host-3, host-4
```

Before removing host-1 from RS, change host-a cname:

```
CNAMES: host-a -> host4, host-b -> host-2, host-c -> host-3
RS: host-1, host-2, host-3, host-4
```

Finally, remove host-1 from RS:

```
CNAMES: host-a -> host4, host-b -> host-2, host-c -> host-3
RS: host-2, host-3, host-4
```

Is this the appropriate way to solve this problem, or is there something simpler?